# I declared a variable, but it's "no defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like a complete idiot here. Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var className = $(this).attr('id');
$(":button").addClass(className);


});
```

This might sound stupid, but what I want to do is select all the buttons on the page, and attach a class name to it with the same exact name as the id that's already attached to it.

It's not working, and when I open the console and just type className it tells me that className is not defined.

Can someone maybe tell me why this was downvoted? Or why most of my questions get downvoted for no reason causing me to have a question ban?

Is stackoverflow garbage, or is it just the people using it that are garbage? This is really rather frustrating.

Comment: what is `this` and `variable` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that you don't have scope to apply your idea. $(this) scope in your case will rely on Window object or some stuff, you don't want that. Using each function you can achieve what you want working with the right scope needed. Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").each(function(){
     $(this).addClass($(this).attr('id'));
});

});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! 

So the .each is kind of a super easy way of doing a loop in a way? Instead of having to try and create a for loop that loops through all the selected buttons, I just use .each and it applies my function to each button it finds?

One question, why didn't I have to do $(":button")  with the colon?

Comment: Yes, each is the easier loop ever! Each is foreach equivalent, passing through the objects, applying the anonymous function (or other function) to them. I removed the colon because the scope that you want is so global that you don't need that.

Comment: Ah, just to remember: the $() operator already sweeps through the screen searching for the identifier, but your routine is so specific that you would need each.

$(' button').addClass ='test' will add to ALL YOUR BUTTONS the test class, without need any other verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Your current `$(this)` doesn't refer to any buttons. You need to nest your assignment in a `.each` loop which will scope `this` as the loop's button iterator:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':button').each(function(i, obj) {
        var currID = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).addClass(currID);
    });
});
```